# How to do a complete backup on Windows 10?

Tags: windows, windows-10, backup

From what I've researched, Windows 10 has 2 kinds of backup

1. File History
2. Backup and Restore (windows 7)

However, none of these actually do a complete/full backup of C or other drives. What I mean by complete/full backup is a backup including folders, registry, programs and others (excluding User settings) so that when you restore the backup to the target computer that has a fresh installation of Windows 10, it would just be like continuing from the source computer.

Is there such a feature or software that can do that? The model of the source and target computer is HP Elitebook 8570p. I'm using Windows 10 Pro 64-bit.

Comment: I think you are looking for a system image instead of backup.

Comment: Windows 10 has a feature for this called System Reset. You can reset windows to a fresh install and choose whether you want to keep your files or not (Only the install drive is affected, other drives will always remain unaffected). So there's no need to do a backup if you want to go back to when windows was just installed.

Comment: 2. is what you are looking for. Why do you say it's not? Did you try it? It can even backup and restore the normally hidden rescue partition needed to do a factory restore.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Full Backup steps:

1. Go to Control Panel by right-clicking on the `Start`.
2. Connect an external USB hard drive with enough free space on it.
3. Click on `Backup and Restore (Windows 7)`.
4. Click on `Create a system image`.
5. Follow backup wizard - point to destination external HDD when you
   asked where to save backup
6. Click <kbd>Next</kbd> then <kbd>Start backup</kbd>

The backup would take a lot of time.

---

To restore system from backup:
You would need Windows installation disk that you can get from Microsoft [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10) in case you replaced broken hard drive.

Steps to recovery:

1. Connect the USB drive where you made the `system image backup` and
   reboot your computer with the Windows installation disk.
2. During Windows setup, choose `Repair your computer` (link in bottom
   left corner)
3. Click on `Troubleshoot`
4. Click `Advanced options`
5. Select  `System Image Recovery`
6. Select operating system you want to recover then click <kbd>Next</kbd> and <kbd>Finish</kbd>

Comment: You can also backup directly to a Windows network share.

Comment: Does something like backing up Drive C: to another internal drive (assuming they are separate drives, not partitions) work ?

Comment: @Overmind: It is supported.

Comment: I recommend against using the Windows 7 backup solution. It is a know issue that restoration can sometimes be extremely slow. Imagine having to wait sixteen days to restore your computer! Microsoft knows about this issue but instead has chosen to deprecate it instead. I advise using a third-party backup solution instead. Or at least, test it out before the doomsday comes.

Comment: Ahh... I didn't know there was a third option!

Comment: I like Macrum Reflect. It's free, quick, supports compression and - best of all - you can mount a recovery image and pull files and folders out of it as if it was another hard drive plugged in. I'm not sure if Windows System Recovery supports that.

Comment: @Richard Windows's backup is just virtual hard disks aka VHD that can be mounted for file extraction.